# Since the result of malloc does not seem to be guaranteed to be aligned to anything, is it even usable?

Tags: c, malloc, alignment, language-lawyer

I recently learned that dereferencing a pointer not aligned for a certain object (`uint32_t* foo = (uint32_t*)7; *foo = 5;`) is in fact undefined behaviour:

C11 section 6.2.8: Alignment of objects:

> Complete object types have alignment requirements which place
> restrictions on the addresses at which objects of that type may be
> allocated. An alignment is an implementation-defined integer value
> representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which
> a given object can be allocated. An object type imposes an alignment
> requirement on every object of that type: stricter alignment can be
> requested using the `_Alignas` keyword.

Ok, very interesting. But `malloc` does not seem to care at all about alignment:

> ##### 7.22.3.4 The `malloc` function
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> `#include <stdlib.h>`
> `void *malloc(size_t size);`
> **Description**
>
> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is
> specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.
> **Returns**
>
> The `malloc` function returns either a null pointer or a pointer to the allocated space.

Therefore: Is there not a very real chance that doing something like the following invokes undefined behaviour?

```
uint32_t* a = malloc(10*sizeof(uint32_t));
*a = 7;
```

We have no guarantee that the return value of `malloc` is aligned to anything, after all.

Comment: No, `*alloc` functions return memory aligned to the biggest possible object (64 or 128 bits usually).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have skipped a paragraph of the Standard just a tiny bit earlier than the part you quote regarding the `malloc` function. From [this C17 Draft Standard](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf) – and it's much the same in C11 and other, later versions of the Standard (bold emphasis mine):

> ##### 7.22.3 Memory management functions
>
> 1      The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to the `aligned_alloc`, `calloc`,
> `malloc`, and `realloc` functions is unspecified. The pointer returned if
> the allocation succeeds ***is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned
> to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment
> requirement*** and then used to access such an object or an array of such
> objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly
> deallocated). The lifetime of an allocated object extends from the
> allocation until the deallocation. Each such allocation shall yield a
> pointer to an object disjoint from any other object. The pointer
> returned points to the start (lowest byte address) of the allocated
> space. If the space cannot be allocated, a null pointer is returned.
> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
> implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned to indicate
> an error, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value,
> except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an
> object.

So, the basic premise of your question is wrong and a pointer returned by a (successful) call to `malloc` will be usable for *almost any* type of object, in terms of its alignment requirements. The situation *may* be different for objects that have *extended alignment* requirements, in which case more specific allocation techniques should be used.